# NextAuth Window is Not Defined Server LogIn Call

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a event flow where a user registers an account, which triggers a POST API request that creates a record in my DB and then should call Next-auth `signIn()` to create the session and redirect the user to the `/app/feed` page. However, since this `signIn()` is made with the NextJS API route it is made on the server side, which is why I believe I am receiving the following error.

```
error - ReferenceError: window is not defined
at _callee5$ (/Users/user/dev/nextjs/nextjs-with-nextauth/node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:330:13)
```

Is there a way to create a session from `signIn()` on the server-side? Is there a better flow I am not considering to create the session after the user is created?

Code:

```js
import prisma from "@/libs/client";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    if (
      req.body.email &&
      req.body.password &&
      req.body.confirmPassword
      //   req.body.tos
    ) {
      if (req.body.password == req.body.confirmPassword) {
        const registeredUser = await prisma.appUsers.create({
          data: {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
          },
        });
        console.log(`Registered User: ${JSON.stringify(registeredUser)}`);
        await signIn("credentials", {
          callbackUrl: "/app/feed",
          email: registeredUser.email,
          password: registeredUser.password,
        });
      } else {
        return "Password does not match.";
      }
    } else {
      return "Form not filled in completely.";
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is clear in [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) :

> ### signIn()
>
> . Client Side: Yes 
>  . Server Side: No

The `signIn()` method should be called from the client side so here, since you don't want to make your function running on the client, one solution is to not call `signIn()` inside it, but instead, make it return `registeredUser` . 
And from the client side you call your `handler` function to get the registred user then use the `signIn()` method to sign in